# Can’t find hyperdrive

Tags: no-mans-sky

I cannot find the hyperdrive, I looked around the crashed freighter, where the wiki said it was, but still couldn’t find it. Is it underground or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

**Source: https://www.ign.com/wikis/no-mans-sky/How_To_Get_a_Hyperdrive**

"**Acquire Hyperdrive Technology**

Once you’ve mastered the basics of building bases, you’ll get an emergency broadcast coming from the nearby Space Station. If you haven’t explored it already, you’ll find that Space Stations are home to various life-forms that can give you items, directions, and more (if you can get the general idea of what they are saying). You’ll also find a trade hub to buy and sell items, and kiosks to buy blueprints and modifications using Nanites.

Ask around the various life forms to find one that has a mysterious message to you, sending you back to your base planet with the location of a Distress Signal.

**Reach the Distress Beacon**

Heading back down to the planet, you’ll come across a huge crashed frigate, with debris everywhere. Make sure to land in the circle that glows green when you slow down near it, as it won’t expend fuel to launch for areas like these.

Look around for a pod with the transmission that was broadcasting - and request the logs to find a Hyperdrive Blueprint - the item you need to finally leave the galaxy your in and start travelling across the universe.

**Note: Before leaving the crashed frigate - be sure to look around with your scanner: You’ll see icons that mark buried Cargo Pods. You’ll need to use your Terrain Manipulator to dig into the earth to find these crashed pods, but each of them has a superconductive lock that only takes a bit of Sodium Nitrate to unlock, and you can get very lucrative items inside - like Unstable Gel. Just make sure you leave quickly as opening pods will release a cloud of radiation that can eat up your shielding quickly.**

**Craft the Hyperdrive**
To craft a Hyperdrive from a blueprint, you’ll need the following:

- 125 Chromatic Metal
- 5 Microprocessors

**Chromatic Metal** just needs some refined Copper, which you already have the tools to extract - you’ll just need to find one or two deposits to amass 250 Copper, and have pack plenty of spare Ferrite Dust to keep your laser running.

As for the **Microprocessors**, you can’t exactly harvest them. You’ll have two options on how best acquire them: The most straightforward approach is just to amass a bunch of resources and return to the Space Station to buy Microprocessors using money gained from selling goods (The items you got from the Cargo Pods should come in handy here).

You can also randomly find Microprocessors by searching the Cargo Drops that dot the landscape (they appear as treasure chests on your scanner). It’s not exactly reliable, but it can save some money while exploring.

Whichever method you choose, once you have everything you need, install the technology on your ship to equip the Hyperdrive - but of course you’ll still need fuel to be able to jump to a new star system."

Comment: Ok, I’ll make sure to check it out

Comment: If you've hired a scientist, following their quest chain will teach you to make microprocessors yourself.

Comment: Sadly I don't think you can get to the quests that let you get a scientist before visiting other star systems.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a red icon that you followed to get there and it sould bring you to an accessable panel (it is possible that it glitched like it did for me and you will need to leave the planet and come back). Good luck!